# htaccess rewrite rule %20 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following rewrite code to prettify the url `http://localhost/about.php?about_key=test%20tester` to `http://localhost/about/test%20tester`

Code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteRule ^about/(\w+)$ about_user.php?about_key=$1
```

but I get a object not found error,after some time I found out that the `%20` in the URL is the problem. So my question is, how do I make this work?

Comment: why not fix the URL? How is that prettifying the URL if you have an encoded space in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stuff in the URI like `%20` gets decoded before the URI is matched against rewrite rules. That means `%20` gets turned into a space, and your regex `\w` won't match against whitespace. Try changing your regex to:

```
RewriteRule ^about/([\w\s]+)$ about_user.php?about_key=$1
```